# ASP Pages Running on IIS7 But Not Pulling Include Files

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

We're working on upgrading our site from Server 2003 running IIS6 to Server 2008 R2 running IIS7. We've been able to work through most issues thus far but have encountered one that has us stumped: .ASP pages aren't pulling in the include file that's being referenced. Here's an example:

> virtual="/scripts_path.asp" -->

This is preventing our site's main menu from being pulled in. Based on what I've read on these "Interwebz," the frequent causes of this problem are ASP not being installed and ASP Parent Paths not being enabled. Unfortunately, ASP *is* installed and parent paths *are* enabled.

There have been some semi-similar questions posted here on SO but, regrettably, haven't been answered completely or just weren't relevant.

Anyone ever encountered something similar?

Now, if you'll excuse me, I'm going to go drown my sorrows... with a plate full of brownies.

Comment: Hi Jason. Did you manage to find a solution to this. I have exactly the same problem. If my include file URL has ../ to go back a directory it fails. If it goes forward in to a directory it's fine!

Answer (score 0):

try using `path="C:\some\path"` instead. The virtual to physical mapper is sometimes disabled. (`server.mappath` for example)

also the real example would be good to have.